# How to upload the gradle build java project into sonar server

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I have added the sonar properties into my build.gradle file to upload the project into server when build the project using gradle. below is my build.gradle file.

```
import org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
apply plugin: "jacoco"
group = 'com.example.service'
sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}
findbugs {
        // make findbugs non build breaking
        ignoreFailures = true
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    compile "org.codehaus.sonar.runner:sonar-runner-api:2.4"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
test {
    systemProperties 'property': 'value'
}
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.projectName", "$project.name"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "$project.group:$project.name"
        property "sonar.projectBaseDir","$project.projectDir"
        property "sonar.working.directory","$project.buildDir/sonar"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "${project.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec"
    }
}
test {
    jacoco {
      destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
    }
}
uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
```

But when I build the project from eclipse nothing happens. No error message in the console, and project is also not uploaded to the sonar server.

Does anyone know how to upload the project into the Sonar Server when building with Gradle?

Comment: Are you running sonarRunner task?

Answer (score 0):

See couple of my posts and you'll find what you are looking for. Mainly, you have to use:

1. apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
2. Then, I have following config in < YOUR_GRADLE_HOME >/init.d/someglobal.gradle file

```
allprojects {

   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'codenarc'
   apply plugin: 'pmd'
   apply plugin: 'findbugs'
   apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
   apply plugin: 'jacoco'

   apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

   //JavaCompile(Works with recent Gradle versions) or Compile (works with Gradle 1.6)
   //tasks.withType(Compile) {
   tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
     options.debug = true
     options.compilerArgs = ["-g"]
   }

   //You don't need sourceSets if your project is following Maven/Gradle standard structure. In my case, we don't follow src/main/java but have src/java thus, in the global file, I have dont_change_me as the value for sourceSets main java and I'm setting it to src/java in the Project's build.gradle. dont_change_me is required here as I'm/was using sourceSet.main.xx.xxx values in few of the tasks here.

   sourceSets {
      main {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }
      test {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }
      integrationTest {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }
      acceptanceTest {
         java {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
         resources {
            srcDir 'dont_change_me'
         }
      }

   }

   def sonarServerUrl = "kobalori.company.com"

   sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
         property "sonar.host.url", "http://$sonarServerUrl:9000"
         property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:tcp://$sonarServerUrl:9092/sonar"
         property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "org.h2.Driver"
         property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
         property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar"
         property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
         property "sonar.surefire.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
         //property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"
         property "sonar.binaries", "build/classes/main"
         property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/classes/main"
        // property "sonar.libraries", "build/libs/*.jar"
         property "sonar.sources", "src/java"
         //property "sonar.sources", "src/main/groovy"
         //property "sonar.sources", "src/java, src/main/groovy"
         //property "sonar.tests", "test/java, src/test/groovy, src/groovy-test, src/java-test"
         //property "sonar.tests", "src/test/groovy"
         property "sonar.tests", "test/java, src/java-test"

         //properties ["sonar.sources"] = sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs
         //properties ["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.test.allJava.srcDirs
         //properties ["sonar.tests"] += sourceSets.integrationTest.allJava.srcDirs

      }
   }

   //sonarRunner {
   // toolVersion = '2.4'
   //}


   checkstyle {
        configFile = new File(rootDir, "config/checkstyle.xml")
        ignoreFailures = true
        //sourceSets = [sourceSets.main, sourceSets.test, sourceSets.integrationTest]
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
   }


   findbugs {
        ignoreFailures = true
        sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
        //toolVersion = "2.0.3"
   }

  // pmd {
  //      ruleSets = ["basic", "braces", "design"]
  //      ignoreFailures = true
  // }

  //Required with Gradle 2.0+ -- 2.0+ -- 2.3
  pmd {
       ruleSets = ["java-basic", "java-braces", "java-design" ]
       ignoreFailures = true
  }

 //Try this or later version too.
 //pmd {
 // toolVersion = '4.3'
 //}

   jacoco {
        //toolVersion = "0.6.2.201302030002"
        //toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
        //toolVersion = "0.7.1.201404171759"
        toolVersion = "0.7.2.201409121644"

        reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")

   }

task testReport(type: TestReport) {
    destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/allTests")
    //testResultDirs = file("$buildDir/test-results/allTests")
}


   test {
     maxParallelForks = 5
     forkEvery = 50
     ignoreFailures = true

     //testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/UT")
     //destinationDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/UT")
     //testResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/UT")

     //testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

     //onOutput { descriptor, event ->
     //    logger.lifecycle("Test: " + descriptor + " produced standard out/err: " + event.message )
     //}

     //Following Jacoco test section is required only in Jenkins instance extra common file
     jacoco {
        //The following vars works ONLY with 1.6 of Gradle
     //   destPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec")
     //   classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")

        //Following vars works only with versions >= 1.7 version of Gradle
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec")
        //  classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps")
     }
   }

   task integrationTest( type: Test) {
     //Always run tests
     outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
     ignoreFailures = true

     testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
     classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

     //testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/IT")
     //testResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/IT")

     //Following Jacoco test section is required only in Jenkins instance extra common file
     jacoco {
        //This works with 1.6
        //destPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec")
      //  classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/classpathdumps")

        //Following works only with versions >= 1.7 version of Gradle
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec")
        //  classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/IT/classpathdumps")
     }
  }

   task acceptanceTest ( type: Test) {
     //Always run tests
     outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
     ignoreFailures = true

     testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
     classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

     //testReportDir = file("$buildDir/reports/tests/AT")
     //testResultsDir = file("$buildDir/test-results/AT")

     //Following Jacoco test section is required only in Jenkins instance extra common file
     jacoco {
        //This works with 1.6
        //destPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/AT/jacocoAT.exec")
      //  classDumpPath = file("$buildDir/jacoco/AT/classpathdumps")

        //Following works only with versions >= 1.7 version of Gradle
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/AT/jacocoAT.exec")
        //  classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/AT/classpathdumps")
     }
  }

  jacocoTestReport {
      group = "Reporting"
      description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
      //ignoreFailures = true

      //executionData = files('build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec')
      //executionData = files('build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec')
      //executionData = files('build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec', 'build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec')

      //executionData = files(['build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec', 'build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec'])
      executionData = fileTree(dir: 'build/jacoco', include: '**/*.exec')

      reports {
             xml{
                 enabled true
                 //Following value is a file
                 destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/xml/jacoco.xml"
             }
             csv.enabled false
             html {
                 enabled true
                 //Following value is a folder
                 destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/html"
             }
      }

      //sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
      sourceDirectories = files(['src/java','src/main/java', 'src/main/groovy'])
      classDirectories =  files('build/classes/main')

      //------------------------------------------
      //additionalSourceDirs = files(['test/java','test/groovy','src/java-test', 'src/groovy-test'])
      //additionalSourceDirs = files(['src/test/groovy'])
      //additionalSourceDirs += files('src/java-test')

      //additionalClassDirs = files('build/classes/test')
      //additionalClassDirs += files('build/classes/integrationTest')
      //additionalClassDirs += files('build/classes/acceptanceTest')
      //------------------------------------------


      //IGNORE THE FOLLOWING
      //------------------------------------------
      //sourceDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
       //classDirectories = files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
       //classDirectories = files("build/classes/main")

      //additionalSourceDirs  = files("test/java")
      //additionalSourceDirs += files("src/java-test")

      //additionalClassDirs   = files("build/classes/test")
      //additionalClassDirs  += files("build/classes/integrationTest")

      //additionalSourceDirs = fileTree(dir: "test", include: "**/*.*")
      //additionalSourceDirs += fileTree(dir: "src/java-test", include: "**/*.*")

      //additionalClassDirs = fileTree(dir: "build/*est", include: "**/*.class")
      //additionalClassDirs += fileTree(dir: "build/jacoco/*T/classpathdumps/com/thc", include: "**/*.class")

      //additionalClassDirectories = fileTree(dir: "build/*est", include: "**/*.class")
      //additionalClassDirectories += fileTree(dir: "build/jacoco/*T/classpathdumps/com/thc", include: "**/*.class")

      //additionalSourceDirs = files(['test/java', 'src/java-test'])
      //additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.test.allJava.srcDirs)
      //additionalSourceDirs += files(sourceSets.integrationTest.allJava.srcDirs)
      //additionalSourceDirs += files(sourceSets.acceptanceTest.allJava.srcDirs)
      // additionalClassDirs = files(['build/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps/com/thc', 'build/jacoco/IT/classpathdumps/com/thc'])
       //additionalClassDirs = files(['build/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps/com/thc'])


     //additionalSourceDirs = files('test/java', 'src/java-test')
     // additionalClassDirs = files('build/jacoco/UT/classpathdumps/com/thc', 'build/jacoco/IT/classpathdumps/com/thc')

     //sourceDirectories = files('src/main/java')
     // classDirectories = files('build/classes/main')

     //sourceDirectories = fileTree('src/main/java')
     // classDirectories = fileTree('build/classes/main')


     //additionalSourceDirectories = fileTree('test/java', 'test/resources', 'src/java-test')
     // additionalClassDirectories = fileTree('build/classes/test', 'build/classes/integrationTest')


     //additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.test.allJava.srcDirs,sourceSets.integrationTest.allJava.srcDirs)
     //additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.*.allJava.srcDirs)
     //additionalSourceDirs += files(sourceSets.test.allJava.srcDirs)
     //additionalSourceDirs += files(sourceSets.integrationTest.allJava.srcDirs)

     //additionalSourceDirs = files('src/java', 'test/java', 'test/resources', 'src/java-test', 'conf')
     //additionalClasseDirs = files('build/classes')
     //executionData = files('build/jacoco/test.exec', 'build/jacoco/integrationTest.exec', 'build/jacoco/acceptanceTest.exec')

     //additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.integrationTest.allSource.srcDirs)

     //additionalSourceDirs = files('src/java', 'test/java', 'test/resources', 'src/java-test', 'conf')
     //additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.test.allJava.srcDirs)
     //additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSets.integrationTest.allJava.srcDirs)
     //additionalSourceDirs = files([sourceSets.main.allJava.srcDirs)
  }
}
```

You can ignore the // commented out lines as I was just playing around. Once your Gradle build is complete, you need to run jacocoTestReport task.

I run this:

```
gradle clean build jacocoTestReport
```

(This will get me a build, code coverage of source main code via Unit tests).

For getting, IT (Integration test code coverage or any non Unit tests coverage), I first run a external JVM (Tomcat etc). Then, I pass jacoco agent info to the external JVM (i.e. Tomcat in my case) like this (where I'm putting jacocoagent.jar inside some folder (tomcat in my case), and telling external JVM (Tomcat instance) to start populating Jacoco code coverage, this will create jacocoIT.exec file for code coverage of main source code via IT tests instead of Unit tests). NOTE: I have this PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS variable embedded in Tomcat startup script where I'm passing it to the Tomcat start command so that Tomcat instance know where to create jacocoIT.exec file:

```
export PROJ_EXTRA_JVM_OPTS=-javaagent:tomcat/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=build/jacoco/IT/jacocoIT.exec,append=false
```

Then I run Gradle task to run IT tests,

```
gradle integrationTest
```

Then, once they run successfully, you'll notice jacocoIT.exec has some file size (but it's still not complete). For Tomcat to flush the code coverage info into jacocoIT.exec file, you have to now STOP tomcat (target JVM) instance.

I run stop tomcat script and Tomcat is now stopped. At this point, I now find that my jacocoIT.exec file is now fully populated with more file size (than it what it had before Stop tomcat).

At this point, I run Gradle jacocoTestReport and SonarRunner task by running (which generates a COMBINED Unit + IT code coverage of main source code via both Unit+IT tests + also sends the info to Sonar by using/setting the -Dsonar.xx.yy=value (which you can easily pass at command line OR in Jenkins (Invoke Gradle Plugin > Switches/options box):

```
gradle jacocoTestReport -x test -x testClasses sonarRunner
```

NOTE: Make sure you pass -Dsonar.xx variable correctly.

For ex: I pass the following options/switches while calling sonarRunner task (this assumes in SonarQube instance, you have the project dashboard with required Widgets in place/enabled):

Here variable *${testType}* has value=**IT** in it. All other variables are defined in Jenkins Global configuration (JENKINS_URL etc or they are available as Jenkins default environment variables). I'm using SVN (as source control tool) thus, SVN_URL is used (which is Jenkins default env variable if your Jenkins job is using SVN as Source control to checkout source code).

```
--stacktrace -x test -x testClasses -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=build/jacoco/${testType}/jacoco${testType}.exec -Dsonar.sources=src/java -Dsonar.java.binaries=build/classes/main -Dsonar.binaries="build/classes/main" -Dsonar.tests=test/java,src/java-test -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=build/jacoco/UT/jacocoUT.exec  -Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=build/test-results -Dsonar.surefire.reportsPath=build/test-results -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports -Dsonar.build-stability.url=jenkins:${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME} -Dsonar.scm.url=scm:svn:${SVN_URL}
```